# Reading csv file with numpy genfromtxt and loadtxt

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

Here is a sample of the data am trying to read:

```
107,4205,934,-1869,97,3917,0,-5154,23,-447
69,-1014,-1449,-4347,177,-1977,4463,2824,1,80
177,-1581,5028,4519,161,-372,5900,1677,2,36
175,-800,-5028,-2571,195,-1794,-6410,-3589,1,-25
107,-1962,-3457,-2336,109,-2018,-7614,-1376,1,9
72,-138,-6388,1388,76,1447,789,6315,1,38
78,1538,6666,4871,67,5074,6119,7611,3,-50
65,-4615,307,-9384,85,-6235,-5176,-7999,3,-12
```

however I keep getting these errors

```
>>> dataset = numpy.loadtxt(r"C:\data.csv",delimiter=',',dtype=str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
dataset = numpy.loadtxt(r"C:\data.csv",delimiter=',',dtype=str)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 
1101, in loadtxt
for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
 File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 
1025, in read_data
% line_num)
ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2
```

and

```
>>> dataset = numpy.genfromtxt(r"C:\data.csv",delimiter=',')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
dataset = numpy.genfromtxt(r"C:\data.csv",delimiter=',')
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 
2031, in genfromtxt
raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #2 (got 1 columns instead of 10)
Line #4 (got 1 columns instead of 10)
Line #6 (got 1 columns instead of 10)
```

I have tried altering the inputs of both functions loadtxt and genfromtxt but nothin seems to work. Also the error about wrong number of columns at line 2 is curious. This data is straightforward without a header. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you try not using string literals? `("C:\data.csv",...)` instead of `(r"C:\data.csv",...)`. i'm not on windows, no errors here copy pasting your data to a new csv & loading with both numpy methods.

Comment: @cryptonome I get the same errors. On windows 10

Answer (score 0):

My csv file had been written in Unicode not ANSI.

On changing to ANSI it worked without problems!